# Sync custom icons between Macs

Tags: macos, icon

I have an iMac I use everyday, and a MacBook Pro I use when I'm not at home.

I use a lot of softwares, and I have customized the icons of them.
Every time I install a new app, or I change the icon of one of the existing ones, I have to do the same with the other computer.
This is pretty annoying, so, I was wondering if there is a software that let me backups my custom icons and apply them to another Mac when I need.

I have found LiteIcon which seems to do a good job in simplifying the icons management, but it lacks an "export" and "import" feature, so it's pretty useless to me.

Is there any alternative to achieve the result?

Answer (score 1):

I am almost positive there is no app that does this. Your best bet will likely be to develop a script that cross checks icon changes at some regular interval when both machines are on the same network with access to whatever drive in which you keep your icon library stored.

Comment: Could you guide him to developing the script?